# Delete first N rows in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Please let me know how to delete n-rows in android sqlite database. I used this code:

```
   String ALTER_TBL ="delete from " + MYDATABASE_TABLE +
         "where"+KEY_ID+"in (select top 3"+ KEY_ID +"from"+ MYDATABASE_TABLE+"order by _id );";

          sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(ALTER_TBL);
```

But it shows an error.

```
03-21 13:19:39.217: INFO/Database(1616): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "in": syntax error
03-21 13:19:39.226: ERROR/Database(1616): Failure 1 (near "in": syntax error) on 0x23fed8 when preparing 'delete from detail1where_id in (select top 3_idfromdetail1order by _id );'.
```

Comment: you can not use delete statement with select statement in single query.

Comment: @Lucifer actually you can. But you can't put a delete inside a select. see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html the expression is the part you can put after "where"

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
String ALTER_TBL ="delete from " + MYDATABASE_TABLE +
     " where "+KEY_ID+" in (select "+ KEY_ID +" from "+ MYDATABASE_TABLE+" order by _id LIMIT 3);";
```

- there is no "top 3" command in sqlite I know of, you have to add a limit
- watch out for spaces when you add strings together : `"delete from" + TABLE + "where" = "delete frommytablewhere"`

---

This approach uses two steps to delete the first N rows.

1. Find the first N rows:

   `SELECT id_column FROM table_name ORDER BY id_column LIMIT 3`

   The result is a list of ids that represent the first N (here: 3) rows. The `ORDER BY` part is important since SQLite does not guarantee any order without that clause. Without `ORDER BY` the statement could delete 3 random rows.
2. Delete any row from the table that matches the list of ids:

   `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id_column IN ( {Result of step 1} )`

   If the result from step 1 is empty nothing will happen, if there are less than N rows just these will be deleted.

   It is important to note that the `id_column` has to be unique, otherwise more than the intended rows will be deleted. In case the column that is used for ordering is not unique the whole statement can be changed to `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE unique_column IN (SELECT unique_column FROM table_name ORDER BY sort_column LIMIT 3)`. Hint: SQLite's [`ROWID`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) is a good candidate for `unique_column` when deleting on tables (may not work when deleting on views - not sure here).

To delete the **last** N rows the sort order has to be reversed to descending (`DESC`):

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE unique_column IN (
    SELECT unique_column FROM table_name ORDER BY sort_column DESC LIMIT 3
  )
```

To delete the N<sup>th</sup> to M<sup>th</sup> row the `LIMIT` clause can be extended by an `OFFSET`. Example below would skip the first 2 rows and return / delete the next 3.

```
SELECT unique_column FROM table_name ORDER BY sort_column LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2
```

Setting the `LIMIT` to a negative value (e.g. `LIMIT -1 OFFSET 2`) would return all rows besides the first 2 resulting in deletion of everything but the first 2 rows - that could also be accomplished by turning the `SELECT .. WHERE .. IN ()` into `SELECT .. WHERE .. NOT IN ()`

---

SQLite has an [option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) to enable the `ORDER BY x LIMIT n` part directly in the `DELETE` statement without a sub-query. That option is **not enabled on Android** and can't be activated but this might be of interest to people using SQLite on other systems:

```
 DELETE FROM table_name ORDER BY sort_column LIMIT 3
```

Comment: 03-21 13:26:33.716: INFO/Database(1647): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "_id": syntax error
03-21 13:26:33.737: ERROR/Database(1647): Failure 1 (near "_id": syntax error) on 0xd5cd0 when preparing 'delete from detail1 where _id in (select _id from detail1order by _id LIMIT 3);'.

Comment: add the missing space before `order`. You have "detail1order"

Comment: @user933909: if this answer helped you, mark it as correct. (*i.e tick mark from left*)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you've missed some spaces:

```
"where"+KEY_ID+"in..
```

must be:

```
"where "+KEY_ID+" in...
```

Furthermore you need to use the [limit](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) statement instead of top:

Answer (score 2):

I'll do:

```
db.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, "KEY_ID > "+ value, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code

int id;

```
public void deleteRow(int id) { 
  myDataBase.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null);
}
```

String id;

```
public void deleteRow(String id) {  
      myDataBase.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + "=\" " + id+"\"", null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit long procedure but you can do it like this

first get the ids column of table from which which you want to delete certain values

```
public Cursor KEY_IDS() {
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT KEYID " +
                                     " FROM MYDATABASE_TABLE ;", null);


            if (mCursor != null)
            {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }

            return mCursor;
}
```

Collect it in an array list

```
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();

cursor1 = db.KEY_IDS();
            cursor1.moveToFirst();
            startManagingCursor(cursor1);

            for (int i = 0; i < cursor1.getCount(); i++) {

                reciv1 = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                        .getColumnIndex(DBManager.Player_Name));

second.add(reciv1);

}
```

and the fire delete query

```
for(int i = 0 ;i<second.size(); i++)
{
db.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE KEYID +"=" + second.get(i) , null);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Delete first N (100) rows in sqlite database**

```
Delete from table WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id FROM table limit 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following mode: (in addition to the response provided by "zapl").

```
**DELETE FROM {Table-X} WHERE _ID NOT IN 
 (SELECT _ID FROM {Table-X} ORDER BY _ID DESC/ASC LIMIT (SELECT {Limit-Column} FROM {SpecificationTable})  );**
```

Where {Table-X} refers to the table you want to delete, _ID is the main unique-column
DESC/ASC - Based on whether you want to delete the top records or the last records, and finally in the "LIMIT" clause, we provide the "n" factor using another query, which calls in the {Limit-Column} from {SpecificationTable}: Which holds the value against which you want to delete them.

Hope this helps out someone.

Happy Coding.