# Delete in sqlite certain rows with specific data that are relatively old in a table using java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, delete-row

I want to delete for example the first 3 (oldest) that have the color1 as blue.

Example data set:

```
_id  |  name  |  surname  |  color1  |  color2    
  1  |  mark  |  jacobs   |  blue    |  green    
  2  |  tony  |  hilo     |  black   |  red    
  13 |  lisa  |  xyz      |  blue    |  green    
  4  |  andre |  qwerty   |  blue    |  green    
  9  |  laura |  abc      |  black   |  red    
  14 |  kerr  |  jacobs   |  blue    |  green
```

I want to use execsql rather than db.delete.. 
which method is preferable ? 
and what my code should be like ?

I will be using this inside eclipse in an android app.

Comment: _"What have you tried?"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE _id IN 
  (SELECT _id FROM table ORDER BY _id ASC LIMIT 3);
```

Comment: where do I choose i want to remove only the ones that have blue in color1 ?

Comment: @DanJurgen In the inner query `DELETE FROM table WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM table WHERE color1 = 'blue' ORDER BY _id ASC LIMIT 3)` - I tried to explain that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800421/delete-first-n-rows-in-android-sqlite-database/9800582#9800582)

Comment: can you please write how the whole method be in my databaseHelper class ?

Answer (score 2):

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE _id IN " +
           "(SELECT _id FROM MyTable WHERE color1 = ? ORDER BY _id LIMIT 3)",
           new Object[] { "blue" });
```

`execSQL` is perfectly fine to use, especially when the command is so complex that using `delete` would require even more complex code.

Answer (score 1):

It is NOT advisable to use execSql for this or any operation SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE as execSql does not return anything, such as errors or rows affected by this query.

Instead although it takes a little longer to write out

```
Cursor c = db.query(table, new String[]{"_id"}, "color1" +"=?", new String[]{"blue"}, null,null,"_id ASC","3");
String ids="";
String qs = "";
for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
   ids+=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")+",";
   qs+="?,"
}
ids= ids!=""?ids.substring(0, ids.length() - 1):ids;
qs= qs!=""?ids.substring(0, qs.length() - 1):qs;
db.delete(table, "_id IN ("+qs+")", ids.split(","));
```

Here's the reference for why execsql is bad for this situation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])

Comment: myDataBase.delete("quotes", "_id IN (?)", ids);
Here, i'm getting the error that the method delete(string,string,string[]) is not applicable for delete(string,string,string)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited to the correct form, also added the dynamic ? for the in clause (forgot you have to add each element separately than as a group).

Comment: Fixed, sorry I don't have tools with me.