# How to enable SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

"SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT" is a option of SQLite. People will compile their own SQLite and add this parameter to make the SQLite database support SQL Command "Limit" function.

But, how can I enable this option in the Android? I have to create the function to limit the update and delete function for the SQLite database access in Android Apps. And I cannot find any solution about this.

If I write the SQL command with "limit", it will return Syntax error for me. If I remove the "limit", that makes the update and delete function becomes not safety.

Comment: delete & limit combined: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9800582/995891 - should work with update as well.

Answer (score 5):

> how can I enable this option in the Android?

You compile your own SQLite using the NDK and add this parameter to make the SQLite database support `LIMIT` on `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements. Then, you write your own set of wrapper classes to access your custom SQLite library.

This will be very complex; it will be far simpler for you to find some other solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve by using `LIMIT` in this fashion.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why wasn't this enabled?  Seems like the easiest way to throttle updates and deletes, and the need to throttle seems likely in mobile apps.