# Simulate ORDER BY in SQLite UPDATE to handle uniqueness constraint

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table in SQLite 3 thus:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                     title TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                     priority INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL);
```

Here is some sample data, for illustration:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM table1;
id          title       priority  
----------  ----------  ----------
1           a           1         
2           b           2         
3           c           3         
4           d           4
```

I wish to add 1 to the `priority` of all cells with `priority > 1`. Here is my first attempt:

```
sqlite> UPDATE table1 SET priority = priority + 1 WHERE priority > 1;
Error: column priority is not unique
```

This fails, presumably because the update is not ordered, allowing the UPDATE to attempt to set one of the cells in the `priority` column to the value of an existing cell. So, here is my second attempt:

```
sqlite> UPDATE table1 SET priority = priority + 1 WHERE priority > 1
        ORDER BY priority DESC;
Error: near "ORDER": syntax error
```

This, too, fails, presumably because my installation of SQLite 3 was not compiled with the [SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) option.

Because I might ultimately want to use my SQL statement(s) with SQLite on Android, and the latter also [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17788645/82216) have SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT enabled, I had better find another way to achieve my aim than re-compiling SQLite 3 with SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT enabled. Here, then, is my third attempt:

```
sqlite> BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        UPDATE table1 SET priority = priority + 1 WHERE priority > 1;
        END TRANSACTION;
Error: column priority is not unique
```

This, too, fails, presumably because SQLite checks the uniqueness constraint before committing the transaction.

Three failed attempts, but I'm sure it's possible. The questions are: **how to do it**; and within that, **how best to do it**?

*N.B. I would prefer not to rely upon any unchecked assumptions.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right that the problem appears because SQLite checks the constraints after every row update and not at the end of statement or the end of transaction.

I see this workaround to the problem (of SQLite not having implemented `UPDATE` correctly). Assuming that the `priority` column does not have any negative values, we can use them (negative values) as temporary to avoid the `UNIQUE` constraint errors:

```
UPDATE table1 SET priority = - (priority + 1) WHERE priority > 1 ;

UPDATE table1 SET priority = - priority WHERE priority < 0 ;
```

Comment: Interesting; thanks! I don't yet know whether the assumption that `priority` will not contain negative values, will hold true; so I although I have upvoted your answer, I have not marked it "accepted". I had been thinking of trying a COUNT to establish an offset to avoid collisions, but the success of that approach would depend on a different assumption (namely that no value in `priority` is any greater than it would be if the values in `priority` were guaranteed consecutive), the correctness of which I am again uncertain about. I would prefer a solution that does not rely upon assumptions.

Comment: (Or, more specifically, on unchecked assumptions.)

Comment: I thought you are the designer or developer of this database/application so you know the requirements/assumptions.

Comment: This is a known issue, but not considered as a bug : http://www.sqlite.org/src/tktview?name=fc6f41426b

Comment: I'm really sorry to see this closed as "not a bug".

They should also consider changing this line from the About SQLite page:

*"SQLite is an in-process library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine."*

It cannot be considered a transactional SQL database engine until it complies (or tries to comply) with the SQL standards - which specifically state that constraints should be checked at the end of statements (or if deferred) at the end of transactions.